# Why is my Angular services saying "undefined is not a function" when I pass my function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to write a factory and two constructor patterns into Angular. I want the factory to be an Angular service.

So I have some code which (very basically) looks like this:

```
function processFactory () {
     // some code...
}

angular.service('processFactory', processFactory);
```

But the last line gives me an error reading **undefined is not a function**.

[Full code here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hw7a2/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check out what I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hw7a2/2/

```
   var app = angular.module('app', ['processFactory']);

   ...

   app.service('processFactory', processFactory);
```

You need to register the service on the module not on the angular object.